# Pass-by-reference for functions with varying length of functions

Tags: php

I have a function with optional number of arguments, something like this:

```
function DoSomething()
{
    $args = funct_get_args();

    // and the rest of function
}
```

In the function above, how can I define the first argument to be passed by reference?

So when I calling it, I be able to do so:

```
DoSomething(&$first, $second, $third);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare it in the parameter list:

```
function DoSomething(&$first) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // and the rest of function
}

DoSomething($first, $second, $third);
```